# MVC - who decides what to do if there was no content?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

When loading a page that lists for example events from a DB, but there are no events going on right now, who's decision should it be to show a message "sorry no events going on right now..."?

1. Should the model check if the array with events is empty, and call the view that holds this message as static content
2. Or should the view check if the array with content is empty, and if so display a message that informs the user?
3. Or is this opinion based and it depends on personal preference?
4. If it is based on personal preference, what are some of the advantages and disadvantages of either method?

EDIT:
The same question could be applied to: We are trying to load an event, but the event is over, so it will say "sorry, this event is already over". Again: Model's choice or View's choice to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View is the part of triad, which will be *aware* that there is no content, when said view request the list of active events from model layer and gets back nothing.

If you are looking at this in the context of PHP, then your view won't be observing the model layer and will have to initiate the request for data.

Also, if you actually send back completely nothing, then the same view should also set the [response code to 204](http://httpstatus.es/204).

Answer (score 2):

When to show which kind of message is obviously a choice of the view. The model shoudln't know anything about users reading messages but only about its inner state.

The actual question is, how does the view know when to decide about which message should be shown. There are mainly two ways I could think of:

- The view polls the state of the model each minute/second/millisecond/when-user-clicks-button/whatever and updates the messages if needed
  or
- The model itself emits events when its state changes and the view listens to those events.
  But, the model emitting an event saying "my state is changed" is something totally different from deciding to show a message to the user and both should be strictly seperated.

Comment: `When to show which kind of message is obviously a choice of the view.` Sounds plausible. If the messages to be displayed are stored in a database (for example to accommodate multiple languages, but also of course easier maintenance) does the view then have access to the DB to retrieve such message?

Comment: I would recommend to insert an abstraction layer, a component which manages locale specific resources. So the view decides which kind of message to display using some message id and asks that component to provide a message text in a certain language. Whether the messages are loaded from file or from database is no concern of the view itself.

Comment: Is this `abstraction layer` or `component which manages locale specific resources` considered a model then? Or just a part of the view?

Comment: Good question! In fact I think there are different kinds of models but I have never seen any description of the MVC pattern mentioning that. Usually you have your "business objects" (e.g. the events from the database in the question above) which might even implement "business logic". But then there are components which have a "model nature", but only exist _because_ there is a view. Like the "component which manages locale specific resources". It is a model though, since you could implement different views using the same messages (e.g. for different devices or with different layout).